# Scheduling Nifi Dataflow using CRON

Tags: apache-nifi

I have designed a dataflow in Nifi using 2 processors such as GetFile and PutDatabaseRecord to read the csv file and load the data in mssql. When I am triggering manually by hitting Start button, processors are running many times and keep on dumping the data into SQL. My expectation is, the processor should stop automatically after one execution.

And I want to make this process automatic by scheduling the 2 processors to run one after other at a given specific time everyday. I have used CRON Driven option and given time as 0 30 1 1/1 * ? * to run the processor daily at 1:30am CST, but I couldn't see any results and outputs after all these settings.

Please provide the solution for the above 2 queries, which will help me a lot!!
Thank you!!

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not valid cron schedule. Try `0 30 1 * * *`. It should run every day at 1:30, no need to overcomplicate it

Answer (score -1):

cron expression for 1:30am daily: `0 30 1 * * ? *`

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html

```
Field          Valid values
-------------  ------------
Seconds        0-59
Minutes        0-59
Hours          0-23
Day of Month   1-31
Month          1-12
Day of Week    1-7
Year (optional)
```

You need to set cron only for the first processor - GetFile.

The following processors will be executed only if there is some data in inbound queue.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be correct, this tool requires seconds as well, so it should be `0 30 1 * * *`